# How to use graphite collectd on hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, time-series, graphite, collectd

I have 5 node hadoop cluster (Linux OS). I have to monitor all nodes statistics like CPU usage, ram, traffic etc. For that I have come to know that graphite/collectd is the best option. According to my knowledge, this tool only for a single machine. There are lot of tutorials about ifs installation in single.

Can we use collectd/graphite in this scenario?
Is there any other best solution that fits in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Collectd is not the best option you can use. Apache Ambari is more popular for such needs. You can Monitor Memory Usage/Network Usage/CPU Usage and many other things in a dashboard. Take a look at this picture:

[image: Ambari Dashboard]